# How can I know whether the logged in user is a prime user or not using LWA?

Tags: login-with-amazon

I am working on a ***login with Amazon feature***

How can I know weather the logged in user was a **prime** user or not

I have some documentation but it don't have any thing about this

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/login-with-amazon/android-docs.html

```
AuthorizationManager.authorize(new AuthorizeRequest
                    .Builder(requestContext)
                    .shouldReturnUserData(true)
                    .addScopes(ProfileScope.profile(), ProfileScope.postalCode(),ProfileScope.profile())
                    .build());
```